# Set desktop background color from code

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

Is there an easy way to change the desktop background color from code? I'm looking for a C++/C♯ solution that works at least on NT6…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You nees `SystemParametersInfo` and perhaps registry update for desktop color.

- [C#: Set Desktop Wallpaper to a Solid Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309943/c-set-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-solid-color)
- [How to Use SystemParametersInfo API for Control Panel Settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/97142)